# DOM based XSS and the “#” character

Tags: xss, javascript, html

I'm studying the DOM based XSS attack. I understand that briefly is an attack where in the attack payload is executed as a result of modifying the DOM “environment” in the victim’s browser. But I do not understand becouse in many tutorial this attack is related to the use of special characther "#"(hash) in order to not send the malicius string to the server. can I use "#"(hash) only in this version or in reflected NOT DOM based too?

Comment: A value after the fragment identifier (`#`) is never actually sent. Therefore it can't be *reflected* as in a reflected XSS attack.

Comment: Is the use of  "#" mandatory for DOM XSS? I'm a bit confused becouse I see many example where  "#" is not use, but if I do not use it I send the information to the server and it is a Reflected XSS.

Comment: It's the other way round: When the payload is sent as the URL fragment, then it (almost always) has to be DOM XSS. But not every DOM XSS works via URL fragments.

Comment: Thus,  for example using an optional query:                                                        http://www.some.site/page.html?default=1                                                            The part default=1 si no send to the server?

Comment: A query part is sent. But here, the fragment wouldn't be: some.site/page.hmtl#default=1

Comment: Thus, also if the query part is send, it is not change the originally code of the web page. It is only use at run time. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

The URL hash isn't transmitted to the server. It's only available to the client, so the server is never aware of its value. Thus, non-DOM XSS isn't possible via URL hash.

Since the client is aware of its value, it could try to use it, fail to sanitize its value, and insert malicious markup / execute some Javascript code, leading to a DOM XSS vulnerability.

Comment: Then for the DOM-based I no need to add javascript code in webpage using a vulnerable server, but I can change the HTML directely from the user's browser changing the DOM, right?

Comment: For a DOM-based XSS, the server must send vulnerable JavaScript. If you were able to send JavaScript from the server, then it would be a classical (not DOM) XSS.

Comment: Thus the use of "#" is not mandatory for DOM XSS?